# Bind more than 1 collection to a ListView MVVM Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Can I bind more than 1 collection to a ListView? Currently my ListView is binded to a sorted list of coins with Headers. So when the app loaded, it will display all the list of coins that is sorted with their appropriate headers. But then, I have a search bar that will search all the list of coins and will trigger a TextChanged event and will automatically update my ListView. All logic are working fine, but I cannot make them work at the same time since I can only bind 1 to the itemsource of my ListView.

I also have to turn on and off IsGroupingEnabled because the searchResult is not grouped and has no headers, but the CoinsGrouped which is currently binded in my ListView is grouped and has headers.
I can easily do this in the code behind but I want to stay in MVVM Prism way, so how can I work this in using only the ViewModel and the View?

VIEW

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout>
                <SearchBar TextColor="White" 
                           x:Name="SbCoins"
                           BackgroundColor="#6b120a" 
                           Placeholder="Search" 
                           PlaceholderColor="White" 
                           CancelButtonColor="White">
                    <SearchBar.Behaviors>
                        <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                                                      Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SbCoins }}">
                        </prism:EventToCommandBehavior>
                    </SearchBar.Behaviors>
                </SearchBar>

                <ListView SeparatorColor="#d96818" 
                          GroupHeaderTemplate="{Binding groupHeader}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CoinsGrouped}"                            
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoin}"
                          Margin="5"                         
                          HasUnevenRows="True" 
                          androidSpecific:ListView.IsFastScrollEnabled="True"
                          GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}" 
                          IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
                          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}">
                     
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <StackLayout Margin="5,5,0,0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" 
                                               FontFamily="Chunkfive"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Symbol}" 
                                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                               FontSize="15" TextColor="#6b120a" 
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--<StackLayout x:Name="SlBusy" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.5">
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" 
                               IsRunning="True" 
                               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Color="Brown"/>
            </StackLayout>-->
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
public class CoinsPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, CoinsModel>> CoinsGrouped { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CoinsModel> coinsModel { get; set; }
    public List<CoinsModel> coinsModelList { get; set; }
    private ICoins _icoins;
    public INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate groupHeader { get; set; }
    private DelegateCommand<string> _textChangedCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand<string> TextChangedCommand => 
        _textChangedCommand ?? (_textChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(TextChanged));

    private void TextChanged(string obj)
    {
        coinsModel.Clear();
        var searchResult = coinsModelList.Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(obj.ToLower()));
        coinsModel = new ObservableCollection<CoinsModel>(searchResult);
    }

    public CoinsPageViewModel(ICoins coins, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        coinsModel = new ObservableCollection<CoinsModel>();
        _icoins = coins;
        CoinsGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, CoinsModel>>();
        LoadCoins();
        NavigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public async void LoadCoins()
    {
        var coins = await _icoins.GetCoinsList();
        foreach (var coin in coins)
        {
            coinsModel.Add(coin);
        }
        coinsModelList = new List<CoinsModel>(coinsModel);
        
        var sorted = from coin in coins
                     orderby coin.Name
                     group coin by coin.NameSort into coinGroup
                     select new Grouping<string, CoinsModel>(coinGroup.Key, coinGroup);
        CoinsGrouped = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, CoinsModel>>(sorted);
        
        if (Device.OS != TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            groupHeader = new DataTemplate(typeof(HeaderCell));
    }

}
```

GROUPING CLASS

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you asked a similar question yesterday and I suggested a way to solve this.  Why are you asking again?

Comment: This is actually different. I added a group and headers to the initial data when the app loads. So the initial data is already sorted with headers and grouped. The ListView is Binded to this CoinsGrouped and it is actually working fine.

Now the coinsModel which I filtered with the TextChanged event is also working fine only when I bind it manualy to the ListView. I tried casting it to the CoinsGrouped but I am having errors it's because the CoinsGrouped has different parameters.

Comment: @Jason So I'm wondering if I can Bind more than 1 collection to a ListView so I can choose when and which collection I wamt to bind to the ListView, since the ListView has to be set to IsGroupingEnabled="true" whenver I want to load the collection that is grouped and has headers and set it to false when I want to load the List for the searchResult that is not grouped.

Comment: this is the exact same problem as yesterday.  You need a reference copy of CoinsGrouped, and a filtered copy.  Bind your ListView to the filtered copy, and update the filtered copy by searching the reference copy.  Apply the same grouping logic whenever you search.  If there are no search criteria entered the filtered and reference will be the same.